# Ink/IconButton color inside Container

Tags: flutter

I have an IconButton inside an Ink (to give it a Border) which is inside a Container. However the Border is not visible since it is overlaid by the Containers color.

What is the best way to display an IconButton with a colored background inside a Container?

Working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.pink,
    child: Center(
      child: Ink(
        decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: CircleBorder(),
        ),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.android),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Material` instead of `Container` [(see official example)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html#material.IconButton.2)

The reason `Container` doesn't work is because the Ink is drawn on the underlying `Material` widget, as explained in the [Ink doc](http://Ink%20splashes%20and%20highlights,%20as%20rendered%20by%20InkWell%20and%20InkResponse,%20draw%20on%20the%20actual%20underlying%20Material,%20under%20whatever%20widgets%20are%20drawn%20over%20the%20material%20(such%20as%20Text%20and%20Icons).%20If%20an%20opaque%20image%20is%20drawn%20over%20the%20Material%20(maybe%20using%20a%20Container%20or%20DecoratedBox),%20these%20ink%20effects%20will%20not%20be%20visible,%20as%20they%20will%20be%20entirely%20obscured%20by%20the%20opaque%20graphics%20drawn%20above%20the%20Material.):

> Ink splashes and highlights, as rendered by InkWell and InkResponse,
>   draw on the actual underlying Material, under whatever widgets are
>   drawn over the material (such as Text and Icons). If an opaque image
>   is drawn over the Material (maybe using a Container or DecoratedBox),
>   these ink effects will not be visible, as they will be entirely
>   obscured by the opaque graphics drawn above the Material.

See working demo:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Center(
      child: Ink(
        decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: CircleBorder(),
        ),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.android),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

}
```

**EXTRA:**

If you really need a Container or other widget that is not Material you just need to add a Material widget between the Ink Widget and the parent one. (with transparent background)

Like this:

```dart
Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Center(
      child: Ink(
        decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: CircleBorder(),
        ),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.android),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ))
```